# OBSOLETE - SEdictionary: A Domain-specific Dictionary for Software Engineering Terms

Tags: app, obsolete, website

We developed a domain-specific dictionary for terms in Software Engineering called **SEdictionary**. The dictionary includes the the definitions of software-specific terms, abbreviations and synonyms, related terms, and frequent hyperlinks in Stack Overflow.

The screen shot can be seen as below:
[image]

We automatically mine such information from the Stack Overflow dataset with some Natural Language Processing (NLP) methods and word embedding. The prototype website can be accessed in https://se-dictionary.appspot.com/

If there are any problems with it (bug or feature request), do not hesitate to contact me by wchccy@gmail.com.

Enjoy the trip to explore it~

Comment: The link is broken.